# How to create open ChainShape in pybox2d

Tags: python, box2d

I'm trying to create open ChainShape with pybox2d (ver 2.3b0) and python 2.7.5, but it creates additional vertice same as the first in vertices array.
The minimal code looks like this

```
import Box2D

a = [Box2D.b2Vec2(1,0), Box2D.b2Vec2(3,2), Box2D.b2Vec2(4,5)]

b = Box2D.b2ChainShape(vertices=a)
print b

b2ChainShape(vertices: [(1.0, 0.0), (3.0, 2.0), (4.0, 5.0), (1.0, 0.0)])
```

The result is not as expected and is same as b2LoopShape

```
b = Box2D.b2LoopShape(vertices=a)
print b

b2ChainShape(vertices: [(1.0, 0.0), (3.0, 2.0), (4.0, 5.0), (1.0, 0.0)])
```

What is the right way to create open chain shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed through pybox2d source code and found additional properties of b2ChainShape that are "vertices_loop", "vertices_chain"

the right way to construct an open chainshape is

```
b = Box2D.b2ChainShape(vertices_chain=a)
```

Now it works as expected